# Styling a small toggle switch in SwiftUI like the ones in System Settings on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

[image: A small SwiftUI toggle switch]

I am attempting to style a *tiny* toggle switch in `SwiftUI` to match the appearance of the ones used in the System Settings app on macOS Ventura. However, the `Toggle` view does not appear to provide sufficient customization options for size and appearance.

We all know the code for a regular size toggle switch:

```
Toggle("Regular Switch", isOn: $isRegular)
    .toggleStyle(.switch)
```

Is there a way to automatically accomplish this specific appearance in the latest version of `SwiftUI`? What method is Apple using to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [the `controlSize` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/controlsize(_:)).

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VStack {
    Toggle("Default", isOn: .constant(false))

    ForEach(ControlSize.allCases, id: \.self) { size in
        Toggle(isOn: .constant(false)) {
            Text(verbatim: "\(size)")
        }
        .controlSize(size)
    }
}.toggleStyle(.switch))
```

[image: all sizes supported for a toggle styled like a switch]

Comment: Apple uses `.controlSize(.mini)` in System Settings. Thank you! × ∞

Comment: Is there any way to change the size of the switch without changing the font size of the text? In Apple's System Settings, the text is larger than the mini text, but the switch is mini.

Comment: Please post that as a separate top-level question.