# SwiftUI iOS - change toggle size

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
    Toggle(isOn: self.$autoplay) {
    
        Button(action: {
    
            autoplay.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: 26) {
    
                Image(systemName: "play.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
    
                Text("video_autoplay")
                    .padding(.trailing, 26)
    
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    .toggleStyle(.switch)
    .controlSize(.mini)
```

This is what I'm using based on the answer here:

[Styling a small toggle switch in SwiftUI like the ones in System Settings on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954736/styling-a-small-toggle-switch-in-swiftui-like-the-ones-in-system-settings-on-mac)

why isn't it working?

Comment: It works for me on MacOS but not on ios or MacCatalyst.
Similar results when using Apple docs example (that looks like MacOS) at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/controlsize(_:)
 
 Although the docs do not mention that it works only for MacOS.

Comment: Alright thanks I guess I'm gonna use a checkbox instead @workingdogsupportUkraine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for changing the size of `Toggle` is to use `scaleEffect`. The drawback is that you must also set frame and offSet to make the Toggle fit with the design:

```swift
Toggle(isOn: $autoplay) {
}
.background {
    Color.yellow.opacity(0.3)
}
.fixedSize()
.scaleEffect(0.8)
.offset(x: 5)
```

[image]